# Web application with mysql db installer

Tags: php, mysql, apache, installation

I've developed a web application that makes some calculations over csv files introduced by the user, due some security restrictions on the user side, their computers can't access to internet or a local network so I can't mount this app in a proper webserver, so it should be run local.

The users are not experienced to be able to setup a proper lamp stack so i was thinking in how i could package the app in an installer that setups de apache/php server, the mysqldb (and the definitions, also with the users configuration)

I've been checking but as far i was able to find, there's just solutions to transform a php into an exe.

Thanks.

Comment: sounds like php is not the appropriate language for this.

Comment: That's right, but I knew about restrictions when I already finished the app.

Comment: ouch, thats like being asked to build a house, then at the end being told it has to float

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQLite instead of MySQL and use compiler to PHP Code, for example: [bambalam](http://www.bambalam.se/bamcompile/)

To use GUI interface, you can add to your project [PHP GTK](http://www.gtk.php.net) or [WinBlider](http://www.winbinder.org)

Another way to create executable file is to use WinRAR program:

1. Copy php.exe and php*ts.dll to one directory
2. Copy your php program to this directory (console.php)
3. Create run.bat

   `@echo off`

   php.exe -q console.php %1 %2
4. Make SFX archieve with WinRAR.